# cakephp where is session creation found

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I've been trying to understand a couple lines in a cakePHP (version 1.3.17) project I’m making an update to:

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.department_id'),
```

and this:

```
$Session->read('Auth.User.department_id');
```

The code lines above show that there is an array in the Session, which contains a user with a department_id field.

I'm changing the user's relationship to the department_id field.  But I can’t seem to find out where this session variable gets created in the first place.  Is it done automatically, or is there a certain file where it should be found?

(I understand the plain-vanilla PHP concept of sessions; but I can tell there's something here that I just don’t get.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Auth.User` session key is likely being created automatically by a login script.

Search the application's controllers for the use of `$this->Auth` (which is the AuthComponent handling user sessions). It's probably `$this->Auth->login()` which you need to find, but I can't say for sure without knowing your application.

Comment: Thanks!  It was in the users_controller in a function called login().